# slow file transfer in LAN over WiFi, but fast over cable and internet over WiFi fast

Tags: windows

I have a Windows 7 computer which has extremely slow (stalling) LAN file transfers from my NAS over WiFi, but the same transfers are very fast over a cabled connection. Also internet is fast over the WiFi connection. On another computer everything is also smooth over WiFi.

I started Windows in safe mode, with the same results. The strange thing is that when I open the explorer all starts very fast the first few seconds. Directory listings are loading fast, as they should and if I start a file transfer fast enough it works well for a couple of seconds. After a few seconds everything stalls. If I go to a new directory it takes ages to load the list of files and the same when I start a file transfer. The transfer of a 1 MB file takes 5 minutes if it works at all.

I don't know where to look anymore or how to debug this behaviour. I disabled Windows Firewall, with no result and the computer really has hardly any program installed on it. Like I said, the behaviour is the same in safe mode.

Hope someone here has any idea on where to look or test.

Comment: Have you tried setting up another computer to share files and accessing them from the first one? I'd bet that's faster and I suspect the NAS, not your desktop computer. Many NASes come with cheap, slow processors and other low end equipment. Can you post the NAS information?

Comment: Nick, thanks. But I doubt it's my NAS. It works fine on WiFi from another Windows 7 laptop. The NAS is a SYnology DS413. I'll also check a file transfer from another computer.

Comment: @GerardMeijer You didn't specify any of the WiFi settings. Are you on `802.11b`, `-g` or `-n`? What is the "link-speed" of your adapter at the moment? For example if you're on `-n` and have a link-speed of 65Mbps you might want to lower it to `-g`-speed (54Mbps) because if `-n` is not well supported by your adapter it only slows things down. Another test you can do is copying a file via WiFi from another computer.

Comment: @GerardMeijer - the transfer from another laptop helps. What protocol are you using for this? Are you using SMB? WebDAV? WebDAV is known to be broken on Windows 7 clients (though you're able to transfer speedily from another laptop). I'd probably try to run a traceroute to the NAS from each device (mostly to make sure they're using the same protocols and to ensure that the wait time is somewhere between the computer and the router, or to see if a simple ping is fast)

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out what caused this issue. It was the WiFi channel. When I switched the channel the problem disappeared, when I switch the channel back, the problem exists again. I'm experiencing this problem on 2 laptops with Windows 7. I can't figure out why, but I'm certain that it's the channel.